# How to Retrieve the 'PAVED' Map Attribute Using HERE Maps API with Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest, heremap-navigation

I am working with the HERE Maps API and trying to retrieve the 'PAVED' map attribute for a specific location defined by longitude and latitude coordinates. Currently, I can successfully retrieve map attributes for a specific tile and layer using the API, as shown in the example below:

*https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/attributes?layers=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1&in=tile:401926&link_id=709291533&apiKey=API_KEY*

However, I would like to extend this functionality to retrieve the 'PAVED' attribute for a given latitude and longitude pair, without specifying a particular tile ID. Can someone please guide me on how to modify my API request or provide the necessary parameters to achieve this?

This request allows me to retrieve map attributes for a specific road segment identified by its link_id within a specified tile.

I was expecting to find a way to retrieve the 'PAVED' map attribute for a given location defined by latitude and longitude coordinates. Instead of specifying a tile ID and a link_id, I would like to directly query the 'PAVED' attribute based on latitude and longitude.

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on how to modify my API request or what additional parameters to include in the request in order to retrieve the 'PAVED' attribute for a given location, without needing to specify a tile ID. My goal is to extract road surface information based on geographic coordinates.

Any assistance or examples of how to achieve this specific attribute retrieval using HERE Maps API would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!